# shell script loop through list line by line

Tags: linux, shell, busybox

I'm trying to write a short shell script to loop through a list (given by a certain command I run) line by line and push values to CSV file

list for  example:

```
aaa   bbb   ccc   ddd   eee   fff
jjj   kkk   lll   mmm   nnn   ooo
uuu   vvv   www   xxx   yyy   zzz
```

Need to loop through this and for each line take 1st,4rd and 6th fields into variables so I can do some manipulation on them.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
CSVfile="/tmp/`hostname`.csv"
filter=$( command )
touch $CSVfile
#
for i in $filter
do 

    first=$( printf "$i" | awk {'print$1'})
    fourth=$( printf "$i" | awk {'print$4'})
    sixth=$( printf "$i" | awk {'print$6'})
    cmd=$( cat /home/app/$first/$fourth/out | grep value | awk -F: {'print$2'})
    echo `date +%d%m%Y,%H%M%S`,"$sixth","$cmd" >> $CSVfile

done
```

The problem here is the for loop goes field by field and not line by line.
need each line goes into $i so I can parse it with "awk"

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is the contents of the file and the expected output of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by using while loop with IFS.
Command output stored in variable ($filter) and read line by line by the loop.
I could not find a way to push command directly into the loop w/o variable (I believe this is not supported by shell only bash)

```
#!/bin/sh
#
CSVfile="/tmp/`hostname`.csv"
filter=$( command )
touch $CSVfile
#
while IFS= read -r line
do
    first=$( printf "$i" | awk {'print$1'})
    fourth=$( printf "$i" | awk {'print$4'})
    sixth=$( printf "$i" | awk {'print$6'})
    cmd=$( cat /home/app/$first/$fourth/out | grep value | awk -F: {'print$2'})
    echo `date +%d%m%Y,%H%M%S`,"$sixth","$cmd" >> $CSVfile

done < $filter
```